# Django: How separate the data inside the model based on the user

Tags: python, django

I want to make an attendance system that prevents each user to see the attendance that some users have taken. But in my case, the attendance that the other users take can be shown by every user. How can I prevent this part? These are my codes: Models.py

```py
class ClassAttendance(models.Model):
    Faculty_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null = True, default='Absent')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_ID + "_" + str(self.lastname) + "_" + str(self.date)+ "_" + str(self.subject))

class Faculty(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, blank = True, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=COLLEGE)
    course = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=COURSE)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=YEAR)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=SECTION)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=SUBJECT)
    
    def str(self):
        return str(self.firstname + " " + self.lastname)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Faculties"
```

> views.py

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def takeClassAttendance(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    details = {    
        'college':request.POST['college'],        
        'course':request.POST['course'],
        'year': request.POST['year'],
        'section':request.POST['section'],
        'subject':request.POST['subject'],
        'faculty':request.user.faculty
        }
    if ClassAttendance.objects.filter(date = str(date.today()), college = details['college'], course = details['course'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'],subject = details['subject']).count() != 0 :
messages.error(request, "Attendance already recorded.")
       return redirect('home')
    else:
        students = Student.objects.filter(college = details['college'], course = details['course'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'])
        names = Recognizer(details)
        for student in students:
            if str(student.student_id) in names:
                classattendance = ClassAttendance(Faculty_Name = request.user.faculty, 
                Student_ID = str(student.student_id),
                lastname = str(student.lastname),
                firstname = str(student.firstname),
                college = details['college'],
                course = details['course'], 
                year = details['year'], 
                section = details['section'],
                subject = details['subject'],  
                status = 'Present')
                classattendance.save()
            else:
                classattendance = ClassAttendance(Faculty_Name = request.user.faculty, 
                Student_ID = str(student.student_id),
                lastname = str(student.lastname),
                firstname = str(student.firstname),
                college = details['college'],
                course = details['course'], 
                year = details['year'], 
                section = details['section'],
                subject = details['subject'],)
                classattendance.save()
        classattendances = ClassAttendance.objects.filter(date = str(date.today()),college = details['college'], course = details['course'], year = details['year'], section = details['section'],subject = details['subject'])
        context = {"attendances":classattendances, "ta":True}
        messages.success(request, "Attendance taking success")
        return render(request, 'attendance_sys/attendance.html', context)        
context = {}
return render(request, 'attendance_sys/home.html', context)

def facultyProfile(request):
    faculty = request.user.faculty
    form = FacultyForm(instance = faculty)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'attendance_sys/facultyForm.html', context)
```

I expected that after the users take attendance, they are the ones that can see that information

Comment: Please also add the views.py code you are using

Comment: Note on indentation: parameters in a function call should be indented 4 more spaces than you have now.

Comment: Side note: almost all of the code between the `if` and the `else` is the same. You can rearrange this with a little work to reduce the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the returned objects by `request.user.faculty`.